# SQL Group By on created column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time figuring out the last part of a SQL query I am working on.  I have a pair of tables that I need to pull data from.  One table contains a UID of a wireless access point, and its readable name (Let's say that 0.38.153.35.118.16 has a human-readable name of AP-9999-9-NW).  The other contains thousands of rows of polling data, with each row containing the timestamp of that poll, the UID of the access point, and the number of clients connected.

The raw data looks like this:

```
DateTime                       AP Name                    Clients
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.153.35.118.16.0       3
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.153.35.118.16.1       14
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.203.128.91.224.0      7
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.203.128.91.224.1      1
```

However, each access points has two radios that we want to combine into one result, thus the addition of the .0 and .1 to each UID.  This raises two problems; I have to somehow combine the two results for each line.  Secondly, I have to use SUBSTRING to drop the last two characters and marry the UID to the other table via the join but do so in a way that drops the last two characters.  With all that in mind I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST([SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[DateTime] AS datetime) AS DateTime,
    'AP Name' = SUBSTRING([SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[RowID], 1, LEN([SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[RowID]) - 2),
   [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[RawStatus] AS Clients
FROM 
   [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail]
INNER JOIN 
   [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus]
      ON Left([SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[RowID], Len([SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[RowID]) - 2) = [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus].[RowID]
WHERE 
    [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail].[CustomPollerAssignmentID] = '6C4E621B-A7D3-439C-8402-D692BE67743A'
```

And this is where my mind melts.  All this does is drop the two trailing characters from the AP Name:

```
DateTime                       AP Name                    Clients
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.153.35.118.16         3
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.153.35.118.16         14
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.203.128.91.224        7
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        0.38.203.128.91.224        1
```

This gets me closer, but the join is doing nothing, and I still want to combine the rows where they share like AP Names.  Group By seems the most useful option, but I cant seem to figure out how to use it on columns that I've created specifically for the results.  The ultimate goal is to get something like this:

```
DateTime                       AP Name              Clients
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        AP-9999-9-NW         17
2013-10-09 18:35:23.417        AP-1234-5-SC         8
```

Any ideas?  Sorry for possibly providing too much info.

Comment: `(Let's say that 0.38.153.35.118.16 has a human-readable name of AP-9999-9-NW)` Where are they?

Comment: @hamlet These names are in the CustomPollerStatus table (or [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm normally not a fan of aliasing table names, but your code just screams for it :)

It is a little hard to understand what you are expecting as output, this solution assumes that you want the total number of Clients per combination of a DateTime and AP.

```
SELECT
    Detail.[DateTime],
    -- you didn't tell us the name of this column
    Status.[YOUR HUMAN READABLE NAME],
    SUM(Detail.[RawStatus]) AS Clients
FROM
    [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail]
        AS Detail
    INNER JOIN [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus]
        AS Status
        ON Left(Detail.[RowID], Len(Detail.[RowID]) - 2) = Status.[RowID]
WHERE
    Detail.[CustomPollerAssignmentID] = '6C4E621B-A7D3-439C-8402-D692BE67743A'
GROUP BY
    Detail.[DateTime],
    Status.[YOUR HUMAN READABLE NAME]
```

Comment: It is frankly frightening how much you were able to condense my query after using aliases.  (In my defense I literally learned half of these functions yesterday so I'm no DBA, but still, wow).  The human readable Status name is (oddly) Status, so its Status.Status, and that seems to work.  At least I'm getting results.  Still verifying the data versus the raw.

Comment: Looks like everything I can find is verifying properly.  Thank you for your answer, and thank you for writing it in such a way that I understand what it does despite my near-complete lack of experience in SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, I would suggest that you use aliases to simplify your code.

```
from
    [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail] cpsd
    join [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus] cps on cps.[RowID] = left(cpsd.[RowID], len(cpsd.[RowID]) - 2)
```

Once you do that, it becomes a lot easier to see what you need to do:

1. Do the "left" operation you're already doing
2. Join to the CustomPollerStatus table using the resulting value
3. Group on the AP Name

Here's the code I came up with:

```
select
    cast(cpsd.[DateTime] as datetime) as DateTime
    , cps.[Whatever is the AP Name column name]
    , cpsd.[RawStatus] as Clients
from
    [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Detail] cpsd
    join [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatus] cps on cps.[RowID] = left(cpsd.[RowID], len(cpsd.[RowID]) - 2)
where
    cpsd.[CustomPollerAssignmentID] = '6C4E621B-A7D3-439C-8402-D692BE67743A'
group by
    cast(cpsd.[DateTime] as datetime)
    , cps.[Whatever is the AP Name column name]
    , cpsd.[RawStatus]
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to count the number of clients, just change that to a Sum and take it out of the group by.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  You and Jan basically provided the same answer at the same time, and though I only tried Jan's it looks like yours would work just as well.

Comment: I'm going to upvote you because your answer is almost the same as mine :) You deserve credit for that.